# Possible bug with new "follow" system?

Tags: bug, status-completed, follow-posts

I have recently used the new `follow` feature (which is great BTW!) on an answer that I down-voted because I wanted to be notified of editing and maybe OP will not bother to tag me in a comment and I would like to revert my down-vote if OP fixes the cause to the down-vote.

Well OP did edit (and actually did tag me in a comment anyway), but now anytime I arrive to that question's page everything works very oddly. To name just a few symptoms:

- Can't up-vote/down-vote or open the votes summary on any post on the page
- Can't flag/close/follow any post on the page
- Can't comment on any post on the page
- **Can** open the share window or edit any post on the page
- The shortcuts on the top bar for notifications, reviews etc. move me directly to a new page instead of opening the little summary window.

Opening the browser's console, I get the following errors:

[image]

On any other page of Stack Overflow everything works completely fine so I can only assume this has to do with the `follow` I did. For a more complete description, on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61029423/6045800), I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61029643/6045800) and **another one that was deleted** already and now this is the situation.

*Note:* I do get the `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` and `503` errors on other pages, but still they work fine, so I guess the main concern here is the `Uncaught TypeError`.

This issue is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345965/571958), but not sure if it is the same cause.

---

This is actually my first post in meta so please let me know if any information is missing before down-voting in case this is an actual bug. I know how to provide a reproducible code, but this is different please tell me if anything else can help reproduce the problem.

Comment: issues with follow are being collected [as answers to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network). Check if this is already reported and if not report it there instead.

Comment: I bet this has a very similar root cause as the problem described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345965), which, when encountered, exhibits the same symptoms - open your browser console, I bet it shows an error in the `updateFollowUI` function

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson I wasn't aware of that thread

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance this indeed seems to be the same issue. Although the error I am getting is a bit different, there is one on the page. The symptoms are similar and indeed I followed a deleted answer so that must be it. I guess I will delete this then, and upvoting the answer you linked is enough? Or should I comment that I faced the same exact issue?

Comment: Not yet, if your error is not the exact same, it may have a different cause - can you post the error message you receive?

Comment: @CertainPerformance posted. As I said this is my first post on meta, so not sure the best way to go forward. I would like to help resolve the issue, so let me know if I should leave this post, delete it or maybe post it as an answer to the post Robert and you linked

Comment: Your error message looks to be the same as the one in the linked bug report - `.replace` is being called on `undefined`. But you don't have 10k reputation, so you can't see deleted posts. I bet the problem is that the deleted post exists in the `votesCast` array, but since the voting container for the deleted post isn't visible to those with less than 10k rep, the element isn't found, so for the same reason as when question "Follow" buttons aren't found, an error is thrown.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So all in all is the same cause... Only now I noticed that your link is for your own post. So should I delete this post or maybe link it in a comment to yours? Also, is there some temp fix I can do? I would like to change that down-vote haha

Comment: Yep, that was it, I found an answer and followed it,  the followed answer was indeed included in the `votesCast` array despite not being visible to <10k account, resulting in the error. I'll edit this into my answer on MSO. Feel free to leave the post here, at least for now, it's useful for devs to know that more than one person can reproduce a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been fixed. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much, I can see it is already in effect. The page is now working and I can revert my downvote and keep following :)